# Merge datasets in Python similar to cross join

Tags: python

How to do cross join like dataframe merge in python?

```
df1 = DataFrame({'Col1':[a,b,a,b],'Col2':[m,m,n,n]})

df2 = DataFrame({'Col2':[m,m,m,n,n,n],'Col3':[1,2,3,8,9,10]})
```

Desired outcome:

```
df = DataFrame({'Col1':[a,a,a,b,b,b,a,a,a,b,b,b],'Col2':[m,m,m,m,m,m,n,n,n,n,n,n],'Col3':[1,2,3,1,2,3,8,9,10,8,9,10]})
```

To merge based on Col2 and cross join the rest of the fields.

Comment: Try using `pandas.merge`

Answer (score 0):

You can get this result by joining each data frame with 'Col2'.

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Col2', how='inner')
```